# Let W1 and W2 be subspaces of a vector space V. Prove that W1 $\cup$ W2 is a subspace of V if and only if W1 $\subseteq$ W2 or W2 $\subseteq$ W1.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

[image]

I am stuck on understanding the forward proof.
The line "If $u+v \in W_1$, then $(-u)+(u+v) \in W_1 \Rightarrow v \in W_1$" is not clear to me.

How do they claim that there exists $(-u)+(u+v)\in W_1$, is that by additive inverse property of the vector space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, exactly. We know by assumption that $u \in W_1$ and that $u+v \in W_1$. Since $W_1$ is a subspace of $V$, it is closed under taking inverses and under addition, thus $-u \in W_1$ (because $u \in W_1$) and finally $-u + (u+v) = v \in W_1$.

Answer (score 1):

First, $u\in W_1$ and since any subspace is closed under scalar multiplication, we have that $-u\in W_1$ too. Also, since $u+v\in W_1$ and any subspace is closed under vector addition, we have $-u+(u+v)\in W_1$.